# Push heavy UIViewController with many UIButtons to UINavigationController

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a UIViewController with a lot of UIButtons (each with a custom UIImage), and when I push that UIViewController to the UINavigationController, it does not show a smooth animation.

So basically same problem as here: [Low frame rate during UINavigationController push transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306962/low-frame-rate-during-uinavigationcontroller-push-transition)

But I don't want to hide my UIButtons during the animation, I want something like what they do in this [game](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-pic-guess-word-for-pics/id600716806?mt=8)

which is not "laggy".

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the view which is similar to the one in the itunes link which you have provided then I dont see the use of lot of UIButtons. As adding too many UIButtons will make the view heavy.

> Replace UIButtons with CALayer, as CALayer is light weight compare to UIButtons.

You can make use of 'name' property of CALayer to give unique name to each layer and override the hitTest method to get the layer which you tap and achieve the same functionality as UIButton.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, it does solve the animation problem, but it takes too long to load every button, wait for them to be "layed out" (viewDidLayoutSubviews) and create the screenshot.

Comment: Take a screenshot and include it in your bundle as part of the project so that it doesn't have to be done every time that you push the controller.  Think of it like a launch image...

Comment: This works if the view to be pushed is static and wont change its subviews according to some value.

Comment: prasad devadiga is right, actually the views are not static, therefore I can't do that =/. What I want to accomplish is pretty much the same thing as the game I linked on the question.

Comment: I've just replaced my UIButtons with CALayers, and I still have the same problem =/. I didn't even add the hit test...

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but if I remove the tile images (like the green squares from the itunes app I linked) and leave only the white UIButtons, the animation stops being laggy.