# First push segue with delay 2-3 sec and next push segues are fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my xcode project I have four screens and push segues between them. I found one bag when I go from mainscreen to second screen I faced with delay 2-3 seconds. After that segues to all another screen working fast.

I think probably problem is in creation

```
    self.navigationController.viewControllers array
```

And when I forced push segue the first time this array was created with some delay and after when I go between screens I automatically switched between objects in this Array without delay.

So, my question: How can I forced create this viewcontrollers array when my main screen loading and working without first push segue delay?

My main viewController code:

```
  #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bestScore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bibleVerseLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)initButtonAndLabelViews{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1.png"]];
    _bibleVerseLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueBold" size:24];
    _questionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueBook" size:34];
    _scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bad Script" size:21];
    _bestScore.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bad Script" size:21];
    _startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _startButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.2;
    _startButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _startButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueBold" size:34];
    _startButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 0, 0);

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [self initButtonAndLabelViews];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    _bestScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"BestScore"]];
    [self randomBibleVerse];
}

- (void)randomBibleVerse{
    NSInteger randomVerseNumber = arc4random()%6;
    switch (randomVerseNumber) {
        case 0:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Слово Твое — светильник ноге моей и свет стезе моей»\n\n(Псалом 118:105)";
            break;
        case 1:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Ибо Ты возвеличил слово Твое превыше всякого имени Твоего»\n\n(Псалом 137:2)";
            break;
        case 2:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Написано:не хлебом одним будет жить человек, но всяким словом, исходящим из уст Божиих»\n\n(Матфея 4:4)";
            break;
        case 3:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Hо слово Господне пребывает вовек; а это есть то слово, которое вам проповедано»\n\n(1-ое Петра 1:25)";
            break;
        case 4:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Слова Господни – слова чистые, серебро, очищенное от земли в горниле, семь раз переплавленное»\n\n(Псалом 11:7)";
             break;
        case 5:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Радуюсь Я слову Твоему, как получивший великую прибыль»\n\n(Псалом 118:162)";
            break;
        case 6:
            _bibleVerseLabel.text = @"«Закон Твой – утешение мое»\n\n(Псалом 118:77)";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Second viewcontroller where I go with delay at firs time.

```
#import "CategoriesViewController.h"

@interface CategoriesViewController ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger category1Number;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger category2Number;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger category1SelectedNumber;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger category2SelectedNumber;
@end

@implementation CategoriesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1.png"]];
    [self buttonsInitiation];
}

- (void) buttonsInitiation{
    [_category1 setTitle:@"НОВЫЙ Завет" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_category2 setTitle:@"ВетхиЙ Завет" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _category1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _category1.layer.borderWidth = 0.2;
    _category1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _category1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueBold" size:34];
    _category1.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 0, 0);

    _category2.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _category2.layer.borderWidth = 0.2;
    _category2.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _category2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeueBold" size:34];
    _category2.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Buttons

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender{
    _category1SelectedNumber = 1;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:_category1SelectedNumber forKey:@"MainCategorySaved"];
}
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender{
    _category1SelectedNumber = 2;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:_category1SelectedNumber forKey:@"MainCategorySaved"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Most likely a problem with your code that runs when the view is loaded - show us that code

Comment: @Wain I updated question with code from main viewController.

Comment: So the sleep for 1 second stands out like a sore thumb... Why?

Comment: @Wain it for display my loadScreen image.

Comment: You should never do that, use a timer. Is this the view that you push to then? The one you're going to when you see the delay?

Comment: @Wain I disable it but it didn't resolve problem. I updated the question with code of second viewcontroller with delay problem.

Comment: Nothing obvious in that code, you will need to performance profile in instruments to see what happens during those seconds. Also try pausing the app while it is delayed to see where the code stops.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in several buttons on second screen. When I remove them all became fine.

[Low frame rate during UINavigationController push transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306962/low-frame-rate-during-uinavigationcontroller-push-transition)